# How do I fix the error when using Validation?

Tags: node.js, hapi

I am trying to add a validation for my API. I get the following error when compiling the project.

```
(node:13800) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Invalid schema content:
```

**Here is the code:**

```
    const Joi = require('joi');

    async function response(request) 
    {
        let email = request.payload.email;
        let userRecord = await User.find();
        userRecord = userRecord.find(x => x.email == email);

        if (!userRecord)
        {
            throw Boom.unauthorized();
        }

        if (!userRecord.checkPassword(request.payload.password))
        {
           throw Boom.unauthorized();
        }
    
        let token = await CreateUpdateToken(userRecord);

        return {
         bearerToken: [token.access_token]
        };
    }
   
    module.exports = {
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/api/v1/auth',
        handler: response,
        options: {
            validate: {
                payload: {
                    password: Joi.string()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Note: If I delete "password: Joi.string()" the error disappears

Comment: Damn I used hapi instead of @hapi/hapi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an `object` schema to validate your payload in [hapi](https://hapi.dev/tutorials/validation/?lang=en_US):

```
validate: {
  payload: Joi.object({
    password: Joi.string().trim().required()
  })
}
```

Comment: It's still a error
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Invalid schema content:

`module.exports = {
 method: 'POST',
    path: '/api/v1/auth',
    handler: response,
    options: {
        validate: {
            payload: Joi.object({
                password: Joi.string()
            })
        }
    }
}`

Comment: What version of joi do you use?

Comment: version 6.14.4 - I just installed it today

Comment: Are you sure about 6.14.4 (sounds more like npm)? The current version of joi is 17.3.0.

Comment: Oh, yea, looked in the wrong place, version @hapi/joi ^17.1.1 and "joi": "^17.3.0".
I don't understand the difference and what to use

Comment: You should use [`joi`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi). [`@hapi/joi`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hapi/joi) has been deprecated. Remove the last one and give it a try. And import joi with `import Joi from 'joi';`.

Comment: Well... I removed 'joi' (and installed after), '@hapi/joi' and got the same error, so it doesn't connect it. However I can't use "import Joi from 'joi';" because I get the error "Cannot use import statement outside a module"
If I set "type": "module" then I get Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module

Comment: Oh, my bad. `const Joi = require('joi');` should be fine.

Comment: But no, he gets access to it (deleted it directly from node_modules and got an error that there is no module)

Comment: Could the error be related to the fact that I am using module.exports for this controller and already in the main file I add it via server.route (require (route))?

Comment: What version of hapi do you use? Maybe you can set up a StackBlitz with a minimal approach.

Comment: I am use "hapi": "^18.1.0"

Comment: You should use [`@hapi/hapi`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hapi/hapi) since [`hapi`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi) has been deprecated.